# Negative output for long double

Tags: c, long-double

Why is the following code giving answer as -2.000000 for every input?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{

    long long int s1,s2;
    long double l,y,m=sqrt(2);

    scanf("%Lf %lld %lld",&l,&s1,&s2);

    y=l*m;
    printf("%Lf\n",y);
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce: https://ideone.com/H2KRHF

Comment: Missing headers? Compile with  all warnings (-Wall for gcc)

Comment: Ok, so which compiler, which OS are you using? And how do you compile and link and run the code?

Comment: Can you tell us some sample inputs that you tried?

Comment: I cannot reproduce either. And by the way 'l' is a terrible name for a variable!

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code, and when I compile and run it on my machine, I get the answers I expect.

Comment: Are you compiling with `-lm`?

Answer (score 0):

You might have made some kind of strange modification to your floating-point environment in the compiler settings. Maybe the bit that represents the exponent now represents the number itself.